# IIS 7 Output Cache - Identify list of files cached

Tags: caching, iis-7, outputcache, performancecounter

Can we get list of output cached URLs in IIS7?

I am trying to figure out how efficiently it has been used in our server.

Please refer attached screenshot showing performance counters. [image: Performance Counters]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if its what you are looking for but running

```
netsh http show cachestate
```

Will show you what objects are currently cached in the kernel mode of the cache object

Comment: Thanks John! Is there anyway we can get similar things for user mode?

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing you can do here is look at the FREB log (Failed Request Event Buffering) you can find a nice tutorial here :- http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/19/Making-Failed-Request-Tracing-More-Approachable.aspx